# Call on function when scrollbar reach bottom of the scrollbar window

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Call on function when scrollbar reach bottom of the scrollbar window
My scrollbar thumb will dynamically change size depending on how much data the scrollbar is storing.

Is there an easy way to do this? window.scrollY seem to always be 0.
I'm programming a react component with typescript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js Call function after scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158964/react-js-call-function-after-scroll-event)

Comment: Well, it is something like that, just that somehow, it call on the function 2 times, before when it hit the bottom for the first time.

Thanks a lot...

Any other suggestions?

Comment: That didn't work at all... windows.scrollY is always 0.